# How to delete all contents of a folder without deleting the folder itself

Tags: powershell, batch, network-shares, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2019

I am in the process of setting up a shared network drive, that gets emptied periodically.

Its purpose is to provide an easy file sharing option for the users. Since I can't enforce them to always clean up after themselves, I want this drive to get emptied periodically.

I found and tried this using command prompt:

```
del /q "D:\Transfer$\*"
```

And then this:

```
del /q "D:\Transfer$\*"
for /D %p IN (D:\Transfer$\*) DO rmdir "%p" /s /q
```

But these don't delete the folders, only files.

How would the some code look, that deletes all contents (folders and files) of a given folder, without deleting the folder itself?

Comment: Are you looking for a Powershell solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I delete all files/subfolders in a given folder via the command prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/173859/how-can-i-delete-all-files-subfolders-in-a-given-folder-via-the-command-prompt)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6836566/delete-all-files-and-folders-in-a-directory and a lot of similar answers. Please search before asking.

Comment: @Destroy666 The first question you suggested did not have a solution for my problem, however the second one did have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16462274/21369344) answer, which does work for for me.

Comment: Both do if you use them correctly. In SU the top answer isn't fully correct though as comments suggest, but other answers are better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged for `PowerShell` even though your efforts and attempts were unsuccessful with batch/cmd—this PowerShell solution works as you prefer, and since you are considering "**PowerShell**" for a potential solution too.

This takes a full explicit source folder path and deletes all files and all subfolders beneath the source folder recursively—***it does not delete the source folder itself***, just everything within it.

### PowerShell

```
$srcPath = "D:\Transfer$";
Get-ChildItem -Path $srcPath | ForEach-Object -Process { 
    If($_.attributes -eq "Directory"){
        Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Recurse -Force;
        }Else{
        Remove-Item -Path $_.FullName -Force;};
        };
```

#### Supporting Resources

- [Get-ChildItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.3)
- [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.3)
- [Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this works perfectly. User Destroy666 also suggested other questions and I found  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16462274/21369344) answer, which works aswell.

Answer (score 2):

The **PowerShell** solution can be simplified even further. The output of [Get-ChildItem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-5.1) can be piped directly to [Remove-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/remove-item?view=powershell-5.1). The `-Recurse` parameter ensures deletion of subdidrectories and any content within, but is simply ignored if the pipeline input is a file path:

```
### Single quotes ensure "$" is treated as a literal character. 
$Path = 'D:\Transfer$'

Get-ChildItem $Path | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

Comment: This is a perfect solution, good to know!

Answer (score 0):

- **[powershell](/questions/tagged/powershell)**

```all-ps1t
$RemoveDir="D:\Transfer$"
$CurrentDir=(Get-Location).path

cd $RemoveDir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null 
if ( $CurrentDir -eq $RemoveDir ) { Remove-Item -path $RemoveDir\* -Recurse }
```

---

- **[cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)/[batch](/questions/tagged/batch)**

```all-ps1t
@echo off 

cd /d "D:\Transfer$" && (
     del /f /a /q .\* 
     for /r /d %%i in (*)do RmDir /q /s "%%~fi"
    )
```

---

- **[command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)**

```all-ps1t
cd /d "D:\Transfer$" && (del /f /a /q .\* & for /r /d %i in (*)do RmDir /q /s "%~fi")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the powershell script works, the cmd/batch script however does not.